# How to avoid repeated xaml code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a small UI in XAML where I need to display twice the same thing in the same window. I created a Resources with the code, but can't figure out how to display it.

the resources :

```
<max:MaxUserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="tInfo">
        <max:MaxGrid>
            <max:MaxGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                ...
            </max:MaxGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <max:MaxGrid.RowDefinitions>
                ...
            </max:MaxGrid.RowDefinitions>

            ...
        </max:MaxGrid>
    </DataTemplate>
</max:MaxUserControl.Resources>
```

The only difference between both UI is the Datacontext, so I wanted to do something like :

```
<max:MaxStackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Template="{StaticResource ResourceKey=tInfo}" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=dtgEmployeeOccupation, Path=SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay}"/>

<max:MaxStackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Template="{StaticResource ResourceKey=tInfo}" DataContext="{Binding Path=ANOTHERBINDING"/>
```

What control I should use to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create `UserControl` and reuse where you want. At first you should create
`UserControl`, then add some necessary controls inside your `UserControl`. For example, we are creating `UserControl` and it would be called `FooUserControl`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="OpenExcelFileAndConvertToArray.FooUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OpenExcelFileAndConvertToArray"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
   <Grid>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
           <TextBlock Text="SomeText"/>
           <Button Content="Delete"/>
       </StackPanel>            
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Then just in any other controls you can reuse this `FooUserControl`. For example:

```
<Window x:Class="OpenExcelFileAndConvertToArray.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OpenExcelFileAndConvertToArray"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>        
    <StackPanel>            
        <ComboBox Text="qq" Name="comboBox">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="1"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="2"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="3"/>
        </ComboBox>
        <!--reusable control-->
        <local:FooUserControl/>            
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: The best answer is always the simplest. *facepalm*. Thanks a lot

Comment: @PLAudet I am glad it helps to you!:)